# <class 'psycopg2.ProgrammingError'>

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql-9.1, psycopg2

I'm new to Python. I'm executing this very basic query:

```
connection = psycopg2.connect("dbname='test' host='localhost' user='admin' password='pass' port='9100'")
cur = connection.cursor()
cur.execute("""SELECT id FROM pages WEHERE uri = %(uri)s""", {'uri': uri})
row = cur.fetchall()
```

and keep getting this error:

```
<class 'psycopg2.ProgrammingError'>
('syntax error at or near "uri"\nLINE 1: SELECT id FROM pages WEHERE uri = \'http://example.com/index.php...\n  ^\n',)
```

`uri` is a string and has the value `http://example.com/index.php`

Could you please help me?? This is making me crazy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
cur.execute("""SELECT id FROM pages WHERE uri = %(uri)s""", {'uri': uri})
```

That is, it should be `where` instead of `wehere`. Since there is no function like `wehere` in SQL, the syntax error is thrown.

The error itself is self-explanatory. Next time, read the error message closely.

Comment: @lyxio it tends to happen in the beginning next time try to look at error closely and happy learning   .Between us it has happend to me too :P

Comment: @lyxio the error you are showing is related to the data in your sql not sure  what is the error is but you will get a good response if you asked another QUestion on SO with the schema of the SQL table and your error and give a nice title